# Mixtral Stopping generation midway

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, langchain, large-language-model, huggingface

I am building a RAG system where I have documents with names:

```
ACC-53
SDF-22
SWE-77
JILOP-11
```

I have built a chain of thought agent in langchain that reads the names of these documents and calls certain tools.
The llm model is `mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-v0.1`.
However, when the model processes the document names it sudently stops and cuts the answer midway, always in the same manner.
Some examples may be:

```
The document SWE-7
The information you requested based on JILOP-1
The gas pedal should be pressed as mentioned ACC-5
```

These sentences are unfinished and always stop with this pattern.
After searching langchain method calls i can say that it is not a parser that cuts the sentence and the actual LLM stops responding.
Any ideas about why this could happen?
I have tried setting top_p, temperature to 1, ~0 to include all cases of sequences but still the error persists.
Any solutions?